# How can I easily setup a ftp, ftps, sftp server for local file sharing via filezilla in linux

Tags: linux, ftp, setup

After a lot search about ftp server and ways to setup or join to a ftp server I found that I can easily connect to a ftp server with filezilla, firefox or even nautilus! But the matter that I opened this topic is to setup a ftp server via filezilla for local file sharing. Also I did a lot search about it but all the result for Linux ended to `vsftpd` which is a CLI form to setup a local ftp server, and as far as I know with filezilla client version I cannot setup a ftp server. I think the matter should be clear yet! I want a easy (graphical) way to setup a local ftp server in my Linux. So please let me know how can I do that. Thanks.

**Edit:**
My distro: Fedora 27

Comment: In case you're not bound to FTP fundamentally I'd suggest setting up an SSH server - it should be simpler, safer and faster than the by now extremely obsolete FTP protocol. As a bonus you can simply `sshfs` to an existing server to mount it as a directory on your machine.

Comment: @l0b0 It's a good choice but I'm thinking for a GUI program that let me setup, organize and connect to ftp, sftp, ftps server since I've found that filezilla-client cannot do that! any suggestion on this!?

Comment: No, and it's very rare to have a GUI for server setup in Linux. Generally there are three steps to setting up a server: installing the package, editing the configuration file if necessary, and starting the service. That's it.